# the limit arrow: its label too high

Tags: math-mode, arrows, labels

My question is an extension of [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19431/how-to-write-a-limit-and-how-to-use-large-absolute-value). I have the command

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$a_n \xrightarrow{\scriptscriptstyle n\to\infty} 0$ 
\end{document}
```

which produces [image].

How can I alter this command (hopefully in a simple way) to get [image], i.e. the label is closer to the arrow, so the command doesn't produce ugly additional space between rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an ugly hack, but it does seem to work:

```
$a_n \xrightarrow{%
         \raisebox{-2pt}[0pt][0pt]{%
             \ensuremath{\scriptscriptstyle n\to\infty}}} 0$
```

If you want it to work more generally, you can throw something together using `\mathchoice` I presume.

Comment: It does seem to work, thank you :). I'll accept the answer tomorrow, in case there are any more suggestions.

Comment: what do the optional arguments in `\raisebox{-2pt}[0pt][0pt]{...}` do?